# model.fit() generates ERROR: ValueError: All input arrays (x) should have the same number of samples

Tags: python, error-handling, keras, theano

I have a keras model with several custom layers. When I run:

```
model_.compile(optimizer=rms, loss=contrastive_loss,metrics=['accuracy'])
```

It compiles without any problems. 
But when I try to fit the model with a list of arrays:

```
X = [T1,R1] + [T2, R2]
model_.fit(X, [None]*2, epochs=50, batch_size=32)
```

I get an error.
It seems that it is caused from engine\training.pyc, as it prints:

```
C:\Tools\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.pyc in _standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
124     for i in range(len(names)):
125         array = arrays[i]
126         if len(array.shape) == 1:
127             array = np.expand_dims(array, 1)
128             arrays[i] = array

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Can maybe anyone help? I am using keras 2.1.2 with theano 0.9.0

**EDIT:**

I tried :

```
model_.fit(X, [np.asarray([None])]*2, epochs=50, batch_size=32, verbose=5)
```

instead and now I get the following error:

```
ValueError: All input arrays (x) should have the same number of samples. Got array shapes:
```

and then it prints the shapes of my input arrays.

any idea ?

Comment: Why would you have `None` as the output?? How do you expect to calculate a loss function when `y_true = None`?

Comment: Because I cannot know how many boxes my sampling layer will keep. The output shape will depend on the calculation inside of the layers. It might change.

Comment: But you must have target data. `fit` does not take shapes, it takes data.

Comment: What is the output shape of your model? How did you define the contrastive_loss?

Comment: The output shape of my model is [(None, 3, None, None), (None, 640)]. I use the contrastive_loss as in  http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/hadsell-chopra-lecun-06.pdf

Comment: Ok, but what is the formula? You're using `y_true`, right?

Comment: def contrastive_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        margin = 1
        return K.mean(y_true * K.square(y_pred) +
                      (1 - y_true) * K.square(K.maximum(margin - y_pred, 0)))

Comment: Well, if `y_true` participates, it's impossible to train this model without actual data for `y_true`.

Comment: What do you mean by I am using y_true? Actually my model should work without precising any output. That is why I am just setting the shape of y and not the content

Comment: Look at your formula. `y_true` is there.

Comment: So you mean I need to populate Y so that my model.fit(X,Y) works?

Comment: Exactly. If `y_true` is being used in your formulas, you need true data. Dummy data will also not work.

Comment: For the situation that my Y is generated on the fly and that I cannot have it before at least one forward pass, do you know how I can do it ? So basically I have the input and the model, the output would be generated inside of the layers. How can I train such a model in keras?

Answer (score 0):

I think it returns an error because Keras is checking the shapes of your inputs. However lists (what you are feeding) don't have a shape attribute. Try passing them as arrays:

```
import numpy as np
model_.fit(np.asarray(X), np.asarray([None]*2), epochs=50, batch_size=32)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But in the definition of my model I also feed a list of arrays. Okay, when I do what you suggested I get this error: ValueError: The model expects 4 input arrays, but only received one array. Found: array with shape (4L,)

Comment: ok, what shapes do you get? the number of rows needs to be the same for `X` and `y`

Comment: I see. I printed model_.output_shape and got:  [(None, 3, None, None), (None, 640)]. So I modified the line where I fit to : model_.fit(X, [(None, 3, None, None), (None, 640)], epochs=50, batch_size=32, verbose=5), but now I get the ERROR : AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'shape'

Comment: same as before, X and y need to be [numpy arrays](https://keras.io/models/sequential/)

Comment: But when I do as suggested (np.asarray(X)) I get: ValueError: The model expects 4 input arrays, but only received one array. Found: array with shape (4L,)

Comment: can you tell me the input shape of your first layer?

Comment: okay, this might be a little complicated. So my network has two branches sharing weights. Then, the 4 output tensors of this shared_weights_network go as input besides other new inputs (R1,T1, R2,T2) to another custom_layer. So I defined the shared_weights_network inside of my custom_layer, so I don't need to divide the model in 2 as I need the intermediate output. I have been saying that I have 4 inputs before but actually, my X is:  [(1L, 3L, 480L, 640L), (480L, 640L), (3L, 1L), (3L, 3L), (1L, 3L, 480L, 640L), (480L, 640L), (3L, 1L), (3L, 3L)] nad my y is [(None, 3, None, None), (None, 640)]